# Where is the default manifest file put?

Tags: java, maven, manifest.mf

I'm a Java and Maven newbie and I have a question about the default manifest file.

As far as I understand, a manifest is created when a Java application is built using maven and it is added to the generated jar file.

I've also seen lots of references to a `manifest.mf` file, which can be found in a directory called `meta-inf`. But I can't find it anywhere.

I have successfully built my Java application using `mvn package`. I can see the jar file but I can't find the manifest file anywhere. Is it automatically deleted when the build completes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MANIFEST.MF` file is inside the jar in the `META-INF` directory. You can see the content of your jar with `jar tf your_jar_file.jar`

You can also unzip the content of your jar with `jar -xf your_jar_file.jar`.

Comment: Or simply unzipping it if the OP is on Windows.

Comment: Simple when you know!